Sending Multiple Attachments to an E-Mail
The following line of code will attach a file to an e-mail:
objMail.Attachments.Add AttachmentText

AttachmentText is a string variable with the path and filename to a PDF file.
I want to send more than one attachment. How should AttachmentText be formatted?
I tried putting a comma between filenames (as one online article suggested):
Filename1.pdf,Filename2.pdf
"Filename1.pdf","Filename2.pdf"
"Filename1.pdf,Filename2.pdf"

Try with:
objMail.Attachments.Add "Filename1.pdf"
objMail.Attachments.Add "Filename2.pdf"


Gustav, I did wonder about that solution.  In my case, the number of attachments is variable, so I'm going to have to run the code in a loop.  I'll try that over the weekend and let you know how I get on.  Many thanks for your help.

Yes, a loop should do.

OK, the loop worked.  But...
objMail.Attachments.Add "Filename1.pdf"
objMail.Attachments.Add "Filename2.pdf"
...adds two attachments to the body of the e-mail.
Any idea how to get them in the area at the top of an e-mail?
Thanks again

An attachment is not related to the body. What you see it probably how/where the mail client chooses to list attachements. In Outlook desktop I've never seen attachments listed anywhere else than at top.

Nor had I until now.  They are shown as PDF thumbnails at the bottom, which you double-click to open up in the body of the message on an iPhone or tablet.  On a PC they open up in their own PDF window.
